# SharePoint Publishing Webcontrol Rich Image Field

Tags: sharepoint-designer, page-layout, publishing-page, custom-field-types

I have using Rich Image Filed in Custom Page layouts to add the images and page layout is used for Publihsing sites with variations English and Arabic.

I am facing a veried issues on publishing page and the image is appearing in engalish version pages and not appearing in Arabic version pages after edit and approve the publihsing pages.

I am using controls in Page layouts as below:

```
<!-- Banner Image area -->
<PublishingWebControls:Editmodepanel runat="server" id="pnlContentEdit" style="width:100%" CssClass="edit-mode-panel">
    <PublishingWebControls:RichImageField FieldName="fd351571-2a92-4a94-99de-57d541b33b35" runat="server" />
</PublishingWebControls:Editmodepanel>
<PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel runat="server" id="pnlContentDisplay" PageDisplayMode="Display">
<PublishingWebControls:RichImageField ID="BannerImage" FieldName="fd351571-2a92-4a94-99de-57d541b33b35" runat="server" />
</PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel>
<!-- End of Banner Image area -->
```

Here is the pages for reference for banner image adding to the page using Rich Image Field:

English: http://dwtc-apt-sp.thetribedev.com/En/Pages/Special-Offers.aspx
Arabic : http://dwtc-apt-sp.thetribedev.com/Ar/Pages/Special-Offers.aspx

Any one have ieda why it is working veriedly?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

FieldName should be the internal name of a field, such as PublishingRollupImage, not a GUID. GUIDs are for list ids.